# Sequence SQL SERVER Select Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I'm in the need of passing unique identifiers to my client.To avoid the usage of UUID's I want to use a sequence. In order to do so I took a look at the MS docs and found this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql).

```
USE MyDB;  
GO  

CREATE SCHEMA Test;  
GO  

CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO  
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1 AS FirstUse;  
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1 AS SecondUse;
```

Which fails for me. I'm currently using sequences at another service in my application where they work - but they are used as a default value. The syntax here differs since I want to select the sequence as integer and pass it to my Java server and from there via REST to a web client.

The example was copied as it is from Microsofts docs. Only the database name was adjusted. Example B from that page is working.

`mssql-server mssql-tools` are running on a Ubuntu 16.04 host.

Error message:

> [2017-07-11 16:38:24] [S00016][217] Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 2).
>   [2017-07-11 16:38:24] The connection is closed.

Comment: The error is most likely not due to the code you posted. The code posted here is just fine. Maybe you have some kind of trigger on the database? Or there is some other code you are running which is hitting a table with a trigger?

Comment: I have no knowledge about triggers in that database. It is imported from an old MS Access DB. But I've already tested with a fresh schema - would this avoid trigger issues? (I'm not yet too experienced with SQL). I can tell for sure that we haven't added any triggers after the import. Is there anything else that could lead to such a behaviour? It is remarkable that the Example B from the page is working!

Comment: I couldn't begin to tell you that if it will fix the issue. But the error you posted is not possible with the code you posted. There is something else going on that we don't know about that is causing the issue.

Comment: you can check for database triggers executing this in your database: select *
from sys.triggers
where parent_class_desc = 'DATABASE' ( and without WHERE you can find all the triggers, not only database triggers)